# Splitting <textarea> post on empty line(s)

Tags: python

I have a form with:

```
<textarea name="test">
```

Assuming the user inputs the following text:

```
This is the first paragraph
It has two lines

This is the second paragraph
```

I would like to split this text into a list ["This is the first paragraph\nIt has two lines", "This is the second paragraph"]

I thought this would work:

```
temp = self.request.get("test")
list = re.split(r'\n\n', temp)
```

But it does not. However,

```
temp = self.request.get("test")
list = re.split(r'\n', temp)
```

yields the following list: ["This is the first line", "", "This is the second line"]

What am I missing?

ALSO:

Assuming there could be either one or two empty lines between the to texts, would this make sense?

```
temp = self.request.get("test")
list = re.split(r'(\n){2,3}', temp)
```

SOLUTION:

With the help below,

I've found out that the following code works in my case:

```
temp = self.request.get("test")
list = [l for l in temp.split('\r\n\r\n') if l.split()]
```

I think the line-breaking might depend on what system the input comes from, so it might not be the perfect solution.

Comment: `re.split(r'\r?\n\r?\n',temp)` would work for either Linux or Windows line ending conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `re` module might be overkill.  Just split the content by `\n` and remove the empty strings.

```
>>> s = """This is the text
... 
... I am interested in splitting,
... 
... 
... but I want to remove blank lines!"""
>>> lines = [l for l in s.split("\n") if l]
>>> lines
['This is the text', 'I am interested in splitting,', 'but I want to remove blank lines!']
```

The `string.split` also appears to be about twice as fast.

```
> python -m timeit -s 's = "This is the text\n\nthat I want to split\n\n\nand remove empty lines"; import re;' '[l for l in re.split(r"\n", s) if l]'   
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.84 usec per loop

> python -m timeit -s 's = "This is the text\n\nthat I want to split\n\n\nand remove empty lines"' '[l for l in s.split("\n") if l]'                    
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 usec per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately GAE still insists on grabbing the empty line as well, so I end up with ["Text", "", "Text]. Another issue that I forgot to mention is that some of the paragraphs might have several lines, and I'd like each paragraph to be stored in a single element in the list (updated the question).

Comment: lines = [l for l in s.split("\n") if l.strip() != ""] appears to work, I guess I now just need to find a clever way to join the lines of each paragraph

Comment: lines = [l for l in split("\n") if l.strip()] as well obviously

Comment: lines = [l for l in s.split("\r\n\r\n") if l.strip()] did the trick, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The standard split can have multi-character delimiters:

```
>>> '''1st para
... second line
...
... 2nd para
... '''.split('\n\n')
['1st para\nsecond line', '2nd para\n']
```

**Edit**

Here's a `re.split` that can handle Linux- and Windows-style line endings, and handles multiple blank lines between paragraphs.

#### `\n` test:

```
>>> x='this is\na multiline\ntest\n\n2nd para\ngraph\n\n\n\nmore\nmore\nmore\n\n\n\n\nmore\n'
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(?:\r?\n){2,}',x)
['this is\na multiline\ntest', '2nd para\ngraph', 'more\nmore\nmore', 'more\n']
```

#### `\r\n` test:

```
>>> y=x.replace('\n','\r\n')
>>> re.split(r'(?:\r?\n){2,}',y)
['this is\r\na multiline\r\ntest', '2nd para\r\ngraph', 'more\r\nmore\r\nmore', 'more\r\n']
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this at first, worked fine when I ran it in python, however in Google App Engine it does not work for some reason.

Comment: I see by other comments that it should actually be `.split('\r\n\r\n')`.